# Add years in date field in odoo

Tags: python, odoo

I would like to add three years to the existing fields.date (`date_entree`) and get back the result in the field `date_fin_prev` in Odoo.

The first approach is:

```
from odoo import fields,api,models
from datetime import datetime

class Ca_administrateur (models.Model):
_name= "ca_administrateur"
date_entree= fields.Date(string="Date d'entrée")
date_fin_prev= fields.Date(compute="_compute_date_fin_prev", store=False)
@api.multi
@api.depends('date_entree')
def _compute_date_fin_prev(self):
    for record in self:
    record.date_fin_prev = record.date_entree + datetime.timedelta(years=3)
```

The error generates is "`AttributeError: 'ca_administrateur' object has no attribute '_compute_date_fin_prev'`"

When i try the second approach

```
date_fin_prev= fields.Date()
@api.multi
@api.onchange('date_entree')
def on_change_state(self):
    for record in self:
    record.date_fin_prev = record.date_entree + datetime.timedelta(years=3)
```

But when i clicks in "save" on the interface, it's not effect in the table `date_fin_prev`

Comment: Do you want that the user can later modify `date_fin_prev` , or that value must always be computed automatically? Moreover, you said "three years", it's a fixed delay, or you are considering the value from `duree` ?

Comment: @luca.vercelli yes i think that's what he is trying to do.

Comment: just to be sure. In the first approach, did you indented correctly the code? indentation seems wrong in your post

Comment: Yes, it was a indented problem but the new message error is: AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'

Comment: try from datetime import timedelta if you still have that

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: I go to show two different approaches, depending on what you want to achieve.

First approach: a computed field. `date_fin_prev` is computed and cannot be modified by the user

```
date_fin_prev= fields.Date(compute="_compute_date_fin_prev", store=False)
@api.multi
@api.depends('date_entree')
def _compute_date_fin_prev(self):
    for record in self:
        record.date_fin_prev = record.date_entree + datetime.timedelta(years=3)  # Actually not checked
```

Second approach: an "onchange" method, that is called by the interface whenever the user changes the value of the first field

```
date_fin_prev= fields.Date() # not computed
@api.multi
@api.onchange('date_entree')
def on_change_state(self):
    for record in self:
        record.date_fin_prev = record.date_entree + datetime.timedelta(years=3)  # Actually not checked
```

Comment: When I take the first approach, here is the error message that it generates AttributeError: 'ca_administrateur' object has no attribute '_compute_date_fin_prev'. "ca_administrateur" is the name of my class. the second approach has no effect in the table date_fin_prev

Comment: In the first approach, did you check the name of the method? it must be "_compute_date_fin_prev", i.e. the same name declared in the clause "compute=..." . In the second approach, the table should have a column "date_fin_prev" and this column should be updated whenever the user clicks "save" on the interface.

Comment: Yes, it is the same information! I just updated my question. you can refer to it and see my code.